# How to parse objects in an array?

Tags: javascript

Of the shown code, I need to select e.g Un-Ranked (inside of metadata, inside of playlist).
Then get access to the whole object, so I can use e.g stats.

Though I'm coming up entirely short, anyone got a clue?

Only clue I have is
console.log(data.segments.metadata.name[Un-Ranked])
But then again, I wouldn't receive anything else of the object, so I'm short.

```
{
  "data": {
    "platformInfo": {
      "platformSlug": "steam",
      "avatarUrl": "xx"
    },
    "segments": [
      {
        "type": "overview",
        "attributes": {},
        "metadata": {
          "name": "Lifetime"
        },
        "expiryDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "stats": {
          "wins": {
            "rank": 292589,
            "percentile": 93,
            "displayName": "Wins"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "playlist",
        "attributes": {
          "playlistId": 0,
          "season": 23
        },
        "metadata": {
          "name": "Un-Ranked"
        },
        "expiryDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "stats": {
          "tier": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": null,
            "displayName": "Matches",
            "displayCategory": "General",
            "category": "general",
            "description": null,
            "metadata": {
              "iconUrl": "https://trackercdn.com/cdn/tracker.gg/rocket-league/ranks/s4-0.png",
              "name": "Unranked"
            },
            "value": 0,
            "displayValue": "0",
            "displayType": "Number"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "availableSegments": [
      {
        "type": "playlist",
        "attributes": {
          "season": 1
        },
        "metadata": {
          "name": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "playlist",
        "attributes": {
          "season": 23
        },
        "metadata": {
          "name": "Season 9 (23)"
        }
      }
    ],
    "expiryDate": "2023-02-28T16:47:00.691118+00:00"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use an array's `filter` method to filter by matches. `data.segments.filter(x => x.metadata.name==="Un-Ranked")`

Answer (score 0):

well you can always use a for loop.

But the Array object offers a way to do this more simple. you could use a filter or a find function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
const JsonResponseObject = {data://} //this is your JSON object
const filteredObject = JsonResponseObject.data.segments.find(y=> y.metadata.name ==='Un-Ranked');
console.log(filteredObject);
```

find will only return the first object that match the criteria y.metadata.name ==='Un-Ranked'
while filter will return a subarray with the objects that match the criteria